# How to dynamically choose Item Views for models in Marrionette Composite View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, dynamic, view, marionette

I have a model which has an array of lets call them blocks. All blocks have a block-header attribute. Depending on which block-header attribute i have i need to manage the view/model in a different way. So im wondering what way I could use the composite or collection view in marrionette to render a collection of blocks, using different templates depending on the block-header in each model.

My current work around is like this:

```js
App.view.external_report.TemplateSetup = Marrionette.CompositeView.extend({ 
  __name__: 'ExternalReport$TemplateSetup',
  template: 'external_report/templatesetup',
  className: 'external-report',
  super: App.view.CompositeView.prototype,
  id: 'template-setup',
  events: { 
    'click #cancel': 'cancel',
    'click #save': 'save' 
  },
  initialize: function(options) { 
    if (!this.model || !this.model.get('template')) throw 'No model or template found';  
    var templateObj = JSON.parse(this.model.get('template')); 
    var blocks = templateObj.SubBlocks; 
    this.blockViews = []; 
    _.each(blocks, function(block) { 
      var model = new Backbone.Model(block); 
      this.blockViews.push(new App.view.external_report.blocks.BaseBlock({
        model: model
      })) 
    }.bind(this)); 
  },

  onRender: function() { 
    _.each(this.blockViews, function(blockView) { 
      blockView.render().then(function() { 
        this.$el.append(blockView.$el); 
      }.bind(this)); 
    }.bind(this)); 
  },

  save: function() { 
    this.model.set('template', JSON.stringify(this.generateTemplate())); 
    this.model.save().then(function() {
      //placeholder
    }.bind(this));
  },


  generateTemplate: function() { 
    var template = JSON.parse(this.model.get('template')); 
    template.SubBlocks = []; 
    _.each(this.blockViews, function(blockView) { 
      template.SubBlocks.push(blockView.generateBlockJSON()); 
    }.bind(this));  
    return template; 
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backbone Marionette different composite views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684567/backbone-marionette-different-composite-views)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create two ItemViews and overwrite the function `getChildView` to select the ItemView that you want to render.

Another way is create one ItemView and select the template that you want to render overwriting the `getTemplate` function to select the template that you'll render.